# After removing vertex, create an edge between the adjacent vetices in mxgraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

After deleting a vertex inside a graph, I want to create an edge between the two adjacent vertices that are connected with the deleted vertex in MxGraph. Ex: A->B->C->D is a graph, After deleting 'C' vertex, I want an edge between 'B' and 'D'. The graph will look like A->B->D. I can delete a particular cell like this.

```
var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
            keyHandler.bindKey(46, function(evt)
            {
                if (graph.isEnabled())
                {
                    graph.removeCells();
                }
});
```

But can't create a edge between the adjacent vertex in mxGraph.How to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
keyHandler.bindKey(46, function(evt)
{
  if (graph.isEnabled())
  {
    const selectedCell=graph.getSelectionCell();
    if(graph.getIncomingEdges(selectedCell)[0]) {
      let source = graph.getIncomingEdges(selectedCell)[0].source;
      if (graph.getOutgoingEdges(selectedCell)[0]) {
        let target = graph.getOutgoingEdges(selectedCell)[0].target;
        graph.removeCells();
        graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', source, target);

      } else {
        oldVertex = source;
        graph.removeCells();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

we can get the previous node by 'getIncomingEdges' method and next node by 'getOutgoingEdges' method.Then create a edge in between this two nodes.